# Why can't I change UIBarButtonItem's title?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change `UIBarButtonItem`'s `title`.

But this code is not working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...        
    [self smay];
}

- (void)smay {
    ...

    AppDelegate *apd = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSString *SmayUse = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d月%d日",
                           apd.newyear,apd.newmonth];
    [_smay setTitle:SmayUse]
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Please tell me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you check if SmayUse is nil or not?

Comment: Where/how are you declaring the `UIBarButtonItem` I'm missing it in this example.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`item.title = @"new title"` should work.

Comment: Basically the OP was talking about something shouldn't happen. As others suggested it may not be initialized properly, but I don't think that's the case. I doubt the reason is something even dumber that I can't even think of.

Answer (score 5):

Initialize your UIBarButtonItem like this:

```
_smay = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" 
             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
             target:self action:@selector(yourMethod)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = _smay;
```

Then, if you want to change the title somewhere else in your code:

```
[_smay setTitle:@"Your Other Title"];
```

**IOS 8 and higher**

UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered is deprecated, so use the below.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" 
                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                 target:self action:@selector(yourMethod)];
```

Comment: Please post the code where you're initializing your UIBarButtonItem

Comment: - (void)oped:(NSInteger)newy :(NSInteger)newd

Comment: NSString *SmayUse =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d年%d月",newy,newd];

Comment: [_smay setTitle:SmayUse];}

Answer (score 0):

if u want to change the title of navigation bar programmatically means

```
UIBarButtonItem *aDoneItem = [UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
   target:self
   action:@selector(toggleEdit:)];

navigationController.rightBarButtonItem = aDoneItem;

aDoneItem.title = @"Something";
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure the button is initialized. If it is part of a .xib file, make sure you have it linked up with your `@property` that has also an `IBOutlet` associated with it. Otherwise you need to initialize it programatically.  Also, you should use the method `setTitle:forState:`.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem doesn't have a method called `setTitle:forState:`.