# Toggle edit button to done

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

Been trying to get the button to change from "edit" to "done".  I am doing a tutorial and it seems to work on their end but not mine.  I can't seem to find the issue.

The code:

```
- (IBAction)onEditButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.tableView setEditing:true animated:true];
    sender.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
    sender.title = @"Done";
}
```

Comment: Try looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360780/why-cant-i-change-uibarbuttonitems-title) from a bit ago. It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've just your code in a sample project and it works fine. Can you show more of your code or provide further information

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the hard way. `UIViewController` already provides such a button.

Lets assume you want this button on the right side of the navigation bar.

In `viewDidLoad`, you want:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
```

Then to handle the button, simply override the `setEditing:animated:` method:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

The button returned by the `editButtonItem` method is setup to call the `setEditing:animated:` method for you. There's no setup required.

I assume this means you have added your own table view to a `UIViewController`. If you are using a `UITableViewController` then you don't need the call to `self.tableView setEditing...` since it is already done for you.

---

If you really want to use your own button. Make sure you set the `possibleTitles` property of the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Never knew this little gem existed +1